# Create uWSGI Socket in other folder?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I want to create uWsgi socket in my project folder and not in /tmp/

Here's my uWSGI config

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock #I want this in any other folder
#say in /home/me/Desktop/myDjangoApp/
chmod-socket = 666
processes = 1
master = true
vhost = true
no-site = true
```

But whenever I restart uWSGI with the socket created in my folder, it **[fails]**.
Can't I create the uwsgi.sock in other folder?

Comment: it fails saying... what?

Comment: Unfortunately, saying nothing..

Comment: So does the startup fail without any error message? or do requests fail? And is that the entire config? Have you tried starting on the command line with the same options?

Comment: yes the startup fails like this
* Restarting app server(s) uwsgi                                        [ fail ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found an alternative solution for the same. I created the socket in localhost

Here is my uwsgi file

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
master = 1
workers = 2
plugins = python
socket = 127.0.0.1:3100
enable-threads = true
processes = 2
pythonpath = <>
wsgi-file = <>
chdir = <>
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the following uwsgi config (reduced to relevant parts):

```
[uwsgi]
uid = moin
gid = www-data
socket = /var/run/moin/uwsgi.sock
hook-as-root = exec:mkdir -vp /var/run/moin/; chown -v moin:www-data /var/run/moin/
```

Note the hook which creates the /var/run/wiki/ directory with user permissions before the server drops privileges. Call the directory whatever you want, moin was the name of my wiki engine.

On newer distros, /var/run points to a tmpfs location so that any manually created directory gets dropped after a reboot. The hook definition in this file keeps your configuration compact, compared to adding/modifying another init script.

Comment: Firstly, enormous thanks for this tip. Saved me and I have a solution I need. In practice though hook-as-root does not work with uwsgi 2.0.20-debian and reading and experimenting I find that exec-asap does. I am still not clear on the difference between exec- and hook- (the manual is not clear here) but the second part is interesting, because as-root is not a command by reference to a phase, and clearly uwsgi tries to create my socket before the as-root phase. So I used the asap phase and all is good! I use exec- as it works and hook- has no clear meaning or advantage as far as I can tell.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Just want to clarify: there is no "before the as-root phase". It's a main concept of linux that a process can start as root and then change the user, but it cannot be a user and then change to root. So, uwsgi starts as root, and is root until it forks and the forked process switches the user. about the difference between exec and hook, I can't tell much, but exec sounds more like "the main process" while hook is more a helper. But it's also clear that exec-as-root is not the main process, so it should be fine

Comment: Well hook-as-root did not work for me, and exec-asap did, so the reason, without further testing must be in either the change of phase or the change from hook to exec. Can't say without testing. If it is the phase then I must conclude that asap happens before as-root. As hook-as-root categorically did not work and failure mode is annoyingly passive, uwsgi simply does not create the socket (as the directory it's trying to create it in does not exist) and exits with no message. If I use exec-asap, then then the directory is created and the socket too and uwsgi begins to serve.

Answer (score 1):

unix sockets must obey to file permission schemes.

In the second config you're seting uid=www-data and gid=www-data.
The socket file must be writable by www-data and nginx must be able to read/write /tmp/uwsgi.sock

On the other hand if you find that difficult, using host:port (tcp sockets) will work too and you've seem to be able to do it like that.

Comment: yeah, comfortable with tcp sockets

Comment: This is the right answer, the user www-data doesn't have permissions to create the file in /home/me/Desktop/myDjangoApp/. Don't use chmod-socket 666. 600 would be fine since nginx runs as www-data as well. `sudo install -o www-data -g www-data -m 755 -d /var/run/uwsgi` Then use that path to put your socket in.